# How do I have the scala compiler infer one type from another?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, types, typeclass, parameterized

I want to create a Scala Id typeclass, so that, for example, I can declare that an Id for type Foo takes a Long value, e.g.

```
val fooId: Id[Foo] = Id(12L) // type-safe at compile time
val fooIdValue: Long = fooId.value // able to get the value back out
```

I've tried various ways but I can't seem to enforce the constraints. If I declare

```
trait WithId[I] {
  type Id = I
}

case class Id[A <: WithId[_]](value: A#Id) // A#Id => Any, not what I want!

class Foo extends WithId[Long] {
  type Id = Long
}
```

this allows

```
val fooId: Id[Foo] = Id("foo") // should be illegal unless a Long
```

If I change WithId to use an abstract type

```
trait WithId {
  type Id
}

case class Id[A <: WithId](value: A#Id)

class Foo extends WithId {
  type Id = Long
}
```

then

```
val fooId: Id[Foo] = Id(12L)
```

doesn't compile, saying

```
no type parameters for method apply: (value: A#Id)net.box.Id[A] in object Id exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Long)  --- because --- argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;  found   : Long  required: ?0A#Id
```

How can I say and enforce that an Id[Foo] takes a Long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to get rid of that type parameter on `WithId`.  However, the second problem that arises results from how you're instantiating your `Id`.  When you say `val x: Foo[T]`, you're specifying what type you want `x` to have, but you're not really helping the compiler out with figuring out what type `Foo` should use when it's being constructed.  So... the compiler error that you're getting results from saying to `Foo` that you want the `Id` out of `A`, but you haven't told `Foo` what `A` even is!  To fix it, simply change your usage to

```
val fooId = Id[Foo](12L)
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't expect "switching sides" with the type would matter, thinking if it's on the left it would be inserted on the right, so to speak. Thanks!